# Помощь в написании xpath selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

есть вот такой вот элемент:

```html
<tr class="ant-table-row functions-table_row __expanded ant-table-row-level-0" data-row-key="51"><td class="ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell"><span class="ant-table-row-expand-icon ant-table-row-expanded"></span></td><td class="functions-table_first-cell"><div><span class="function-name">Обход штатного иммобилайзера</span></div></td><td class="functions-table_cell"></td><td class="functions-table_cell"></td><td class="functions-table_cell"><div class="point-icon"></div></td></tr>
```

Который мне нужно найти в таблице по `data-row-key="51"`, и проверить наличие точки `class="point-icon"` в соседних элементах которые находятся на том же уровне, помогите мне понять как я могу это сделать вот примерно в таком виде?

```
 try:
            for point_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('#xpath data-row-key="51"'):
                #if point в 1 элементе:
                    #point = 'YES'
                #elif point в 2 элементе:
                    #point = 'YES'
                #elif point в 2 элементе:
                    #point = 'YES'
        except:
            point = 'No'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный XPath, который найдет все элементы, у который атрибут `data-row-key` равен `51`:

```
//*[@data-row-key="51"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/attribute.

Вы можете найти корневой WebElement и найти в нем элементы с нужным классом:

```
root = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-row-key="51"]')[0]
elements = root.find_elements_by_class_name('point-icon')
```

В массиве `elements` будут все теги с классом `point-icon`. Или массив будет пустой, если таких тегов нет.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, а не подскажите как найти еще и `point-icon`?

Comment: @ФедоченкоЛеонид Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!